# Python: Converting existing values into dictionary in Class without using __dict__

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I need to convert existing values into dictionary in a Class without using __dict__ function. Details below.

---

The current output looks like below (only a portion of the total records, this is just for example):

```
Abair, 131 Laconia St, 7, PHYS271:C|CHEM271:C|MUSC101:A|ANTA321:B
Babeau, 60 Parker St, 8, GERM111:B|COM432:A|ENGR251:C
Babin, 44 Griggs Rd, 9, MECH312:D|MATH142C|GEOG108:B
```

What I need is this output in dictionary format for the course-grade pairs:

```
Babeau, 60 Parker St, 8, {GERM111:B, COM432:A, ENGR251:C}
```

---

My class is below. Class Student is a sub-class of Class Person.

```
class Person(object):

    def __init__(self, name, address):
        self.name    = name
        self.address = address

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_address(self):
        return self.address

    def greet(self):
        print "Hello, my name is " + self.name

    def print_person(self):
        print self.name, self.address

class Student(Person):

    next_id = 0          # A unique ID for each student

    def __init__(self, name, address, record):
        Person.__init__(self, name, address)
        Student.next_id += 1
        self.id = Student.next_id   
        self.record = record

    def get_id(self):
        return self.id

    def add_to_record(self, semester_grades):
        self.record += semester_grades

    def get_record(self):
        return self.record

    def greet(self):
        print "How's it going? I'm " + self.name


    def print_person(self):
        grades = str(self.record)
        print "%s, %s, %i, %s" % (self.name, self.address, self.id, grades)
```

---

The instruction for the creation of dictionary is below. I don't think I am allowed to use __dict__ function.

> add the existing values to a dictionary for each student and then have code which allows the addition of extra course:grade pairs.
>   As far as creating the dictionary, the data in the file is already in course (key):grade(value) pairs so building a dictionary should be fairly easy. Just use split to get the pairs and then again to get the two parts and build the dictionary.
>   So for each student, create an empty dictionary in the initialiser (__init__) function, then split the course:grade pairs up and use the grade adding method to add them to the student object.
>   Then write some code to use the add, change and retrieve methods."

I still cannot figure out how to create such dictionary.

Comment: First of all, `__dict__` is a dictionary, not a function; `dict` is a function (and a type).  Secondly, what makes you think you can't use one of them?

Comment: I can't because that is one of the requirements.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Looks like your assignment spells out the steps of creating the dict from strings pretty straightforwardly: use `split` to get the pairs, then `split` again to separate them into key/value, then add to a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're wanting to split the string of classes/grades into a dict, you'd do it like this:

```
s = "PHYS271:C|CHEM271:C|MUSC101:A|ANTA321:B"
d = dict(x.split(':') for x in s.split('|'))

>>> d
{'CHEM271': 'C', 'MUSC101': 'A', 'PHYS271': 'C', 'ANTA321': 'B'}
```

Comment: how to add that INTO the Student Class, though? How to make it to be a function inside the class? It should do something to the self.record